# Efficient way of finding rows in which A>B

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

Suppose `M` is a matrix where each row represents a randomized sequence of a pool of `N` objects, e.g.,

```
1 2 3 4
3 4 1 2
2 1 3 4
```

How can I efficiently find all the rows in which a number `A` comes before a number `B`?

e.g., `A=1` and `B=2`; I want to retrieve the first and the second rows (in which `1` comes before `2`)

Comment: Is `B` the same size as `A`? Is the question whether one number in `A` is greater than one number in `B` for that given row?

Comment: With `A` and `B` I am characterizing two numbers, e.g., `A=1`and `B=2` and so I want to retrieve the first and the second rows (in which `1` comes before `2`) (sorry, there was a typo in the text: `A` is not the matrix :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go:

```
[iA jA] = find(M.'==A);
[iB jB] = find(M.'==B);
sol = find(iA<iB)
```

Note that this works because, according to the problem specification, every number is guaranteed to appear once in each row.

---

To find rows of `M` with a given prefix (as requested in the comments): let `prefix` be a vector with the sought prefix (for example, `prefix = [1 2]`):

```
find(all(bsxfun(@eq, M(:,1:numel(prefix)).', prefix(:))))
```

Comment: It's considered good practice to give a reason for a downvote. Does my solution not work? Is it ugly? Is it slow?

Comment: It works pretty fine to me. Nice :) (I don't know why someone downvoted you!)

Comment: no idea why this would get downvoted, works for me and is definitely more elegant than my looping method. +1 from me :)

Comment: So what about finding all the rows having the same prefix? (I don't know if I should create a second question...)

Comment: That should be easy. How do you define "prefix"?

Comment: A prefix is a sequence of numbers. Something as: I want to find all the rows that begin with "1 2 3"

Comment: `find(all(bsxfun(@eq,M(:,1:numel(prefix)).',prefix(:))))`, with `prefix = [1 2 3]` (or any other length)

Comment: @Eleanore I edited my comment and answer, try now and if it gives you an error please tell me which error

Comment: @Eleanore With `prefix = [1 2 3]` it correctly returns 1. Can you give a specific example where it fails?

Comment: A = [1 2 3; 2 5 1; 1 2 6]; prefix=[1 2];

Comment: @Eleanore That correcly returns `[1 3]`. But you should call the matrix `M` (as in the original question), not `A`

Answer (score 1):

something like the following code should work. It will look to see if `A` comes before `B` in each row.

```
temp = [1 2 3 4;
        3 4 1 2;
        2 1 3 4];
A = 1;
B = 2;
orderMatch = zeros(1,size(temp,1));
for i = 1:size(temp,1)
    match1= temp(i,:) == A;
    match2= temp(i,:) == B;
    aIndex = find(match1,1);
    bIndex = find(match2,1);
    if aIndex < bIndex
        orderMatch(i) = 1;
    end
end
solution = find(orderMatch);
```

This will result in `[1,1,0]` because the first two rows have 1 coming before 2, but the third row does not.

**UPDATE**

added `find` function on ordermatch to give row indices as suggested by Luis

Comment: I suggest a final `find(orderMatch)`, as the OP wants the row numbers, not 0/1 flags

Comment: Note that Luis's method is better and more elegant.