# Subdivide matrix rows according to object ranks

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I would like to update the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277130/efficient-way-of-finding-rows-in-which-ab), which is partially correlated to what is suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642235/matlab-efficiently-find-the-row-that-contains-two-of-three-elements-in-a-large-m).

Let `M` be a MATLAB matrix, e.g.:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
3 2 5
3 5 4
1 4 5
```

I would like to subdivide **efficiently** the rows of `M` in two sets, so that:

- in the first set `M(A>B)` there are all the rows in which:

  - Either the element `A` is ranked higher than the element `B` (if both the elements are present)
  - Or the element `A` is present and the element `B` is not present
  - Or both the elements `A` and `B` are not present
- in the first set `M(B>A)` there are all the rows in which:

  - Either the element `B` is ranked higher than the element `A` (if both the elements are present)
  - Or the element `B` is present and the element `A` is not present
  - Or both the elements `A` and `B` are not present

In the example presented above, if `A=2` and `B=3`, the first set `M(A>B)` is defined as:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 4 5
```

while the second set `M(B>A)` is defined as:

```
3 2 5
3 4 5
1 4 5
```

Notice that in my case, the matrix `M` is really large, hence solutions based on `ismember` would not be fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[val2, ind] = max((M==A) | (M==B), [], 2);
val1 = val2;
val1(val1) = M((ind(val1)-1)*size(M,1) + find(val1))==B;
set1 = M(~val1, :);
val2(val2) = M((ind(val2)-1)*size(M,1) + find(val2))==A;
set2 = M(~val2, :);
```